# Powerquery extract values from list in column B based on another columnA value

Tags: list, filter, powerquery

I have two columns A and B

A is a normal column. Let's say it may have any of the following colors: black, white, orange
B each B record contain a list. Let's say "white shirt", "white trousers", "orange t-shirt"

I'm trying to get in column B the items related to the color in column A.

If A = white, then I want in one cell "white shirt" and "white trousers".

If I hard code "white", it works, but I can't pass [A] to Text.Contains (or I don't know how)

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"B", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Select(_,each Text.Contains(_,"white")), Text.From), "#(lf)"), type text})
```

Please, I appreciate any help.

Comment: With the following code you can pass a value from column A. It's hard coded to the first row {0} 

=Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"A", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Select(_,each Text.Contains(_,#"Added Custom"[B]{0})), Text.From), "#(lf)"), type text})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to set value of the first column equal to a variable before starting to work with the list in the second column

so for your example

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"B", each let search = [ColumnA] in Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Select(_,each Text.Contains(_,search)), Text.From), "#(lf)"), type text})
```

but in a more general example:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
    let search = [Column1] in 
    Text.Combine(
        List.Select(
            Text.Split([Column2],","),
            each Text.Contains(_,search)
        )
    ," ,")
)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I will play around with the second example. 
The first one makes perfect sense however I get an error.
Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type List.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Key=Column1
Either way you gave me an idea for a second approach. Since I can get the data from a Text field similar to your Column2.
Thanks again!

Comment: I tried the general example and works like charm. In fact, in my use case it may even be better than what I was trying to do. Thank you for taking the time to answer. All the best.